# How can I take a screenshot of a SwiftUI List including all content, not just visible

Tags: xcode, swiftui, screenshot, swiftui-list

I want to take a screenshot of a SwiftUI List and include all content.  I am using a form style list so I don't want to switch to a VStack in a ScrollView.

I have seen some tutorials on how to create a screenshot for a scrollView but that doesn't work here.  There is also a very nice tutorial on creating a screenshot for any view:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image

But this only captures the visible areas of the List.  I want to screenshot all of the List contents.  Has anybody managed to do this?

Comment: Obviously, you have to create a list manually for yourself.